# Google combo chart issue

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, google-visualization

I am trying to create a combo chart using google charts, 
in HTML added below CDN and div

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: auto; height: 500px;"></div>
```

the result of

```
var examname = <?php echo json_encode($examnames); ?>;
var highestScore = <?php echo json_encode($heighestScores); ?>;
var userScore = <?php echo json_encode($userScores); ?>;
```

is

```
var examname = ["Test Name 1", "Full Test", "Knowledge"]; 
var highestScore = ["8", "11", "10"];
var userScore = ["6", "11"];



google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages': ['corechart']
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var graphData = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        graphData.addColumn('string', 'TestName');
        graphData.addColumn('number', 'Height');
        graphData.addColumn('number', 'YourScore');

        for (var i = 0; i < examname.length; i++) {
          if (userScore[i] === undefined) {
            userScore[i] = 0;
          }
          console.log(userScore[i]);
          graphData.addRow(examname[i], {
            v: highestScore[i],
            f: userScore[i]
          });
        }
        //graphData = graphData.replace(/'/g, '"');
        //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(graphData);
        console.log(data);
        var options = {
          title: 'Score Dashboard',
          vAxis: {
            title: 'Score'
          },
          hAxis: {
            title: 'Exam Name'
          },
          seriesType: 'bars',
          series: {
            5: {
              type: 'line'
            }
          }
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(graphData, options);
      }
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/hmcre1fm/)**

I am getting an error:

> Error: If argument is given to addRow, it must be an array, or null

even I searched in google but I didn't understand. Please could any one help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Uhm... Isn't the error message telling you exactly what the problem is? You are passing an element of an array not an array as an argument to graphData.addRow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your passing (string, object). When it's expecting just (array).

**Change**

```
graphData.addRow(examname[i], {
    v: highestScore[i],
    f: userScore[i]
});
```

**To**

```
graphData.addRow([
    examname[i],
    Number(highestScore[i]),
    Number(userScore[i])
]);
```

**Working example:** https://jsfiddle.net/g4vjvam9/

Note: If you want the last column filled, you need to add the value :/

```
var userScore = ["6", "11", "2"];
```

Also avoid strings else your need to use `Number()` like above.

Comment: np, glad to help.

Comment: animation is not working, Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfeel/hmcre1fm/4/)

Comment: need a Ph.D for all them options ;p

Comment: ha ha ha :D need a Ph.D. Actually first time I am using google chart. If you don't mind could you please help me for further issues also.

Comment: Open a new question, after you get stuck. It allows others to get in on the action ;p